# How to Connect UIButton to HTML button?

Tags: ios

This is the code of `HTML` :

```
<input name="nextbtn" type="button" value="Next(N)" onclick="validate( this.name )" accesskey="N" >
```

This is `onClick(button)` event in `HTML`, I want this validate function to trigger when I will press button in my `UI` of **objective-C** code..

I am using **IBAction** and connecting it to `UIButton`, can any one suggest how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Call `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` on the webview you are dealing with.

Comment: can u please tell me how to use this in my IBAction function? with a sample code?